# Google Maps API strict mode compliance

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-5

As part of a research project, I am currently investigating the sandboxing of third-party scripts using the Secure EcmaScript implementation of the Google Caja project (https://code.google.com/p/es-lab/wiki/SecureEcmaScript, https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/ses). I managed to execute the Google Maps application in such a sandbox, i.e. the Google Maps API v3 (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js) and subsequently loaded scripts are executed in a controlled environment. However, in order to make this work, I had to perform two modifications in the first script that is loaded by the Google Maps application (at the time of writing, this was https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/8/2/main.js). Without modifications, the application fails to run because the code is not ECMAScript 5 strict mode compliant. Concretely, following code fragment occurs somewhere in the file:

```
R.cf=function(){return this}().navigator&&-1!=ha.userAgent[Mc]()[tb]("msie");
```

In strict mode, `function(){return this}` returns `undefined`, causing the property access for "navigator" to throw an error. In non-strict mode, the function would return the global "window" object. I found one more instance where such a situation causes an error in strict mode.

At first, I found it surprising that the Google Maps application is not strict mode compliant. As far as I know, there are only advantages to the usage of strict mode. However, I reckon that the original code might be strict mode compliant, but that the transformations done by the minification compiler remove the compliance. From a security point of view, it is very useful to be able to execute a script in a controlled manner. For instance, this would prevent security violations when an external script has been compromised and its functionality altered. Therefore, I think it would be very useful to be able to execute the Google Maps application inside such a sandbox. However, as the Google Caja implementation of Secure EcmaScript relies on the limitations imposed by strict mode to guarantee its functionality, it requires a Google Maps application that is strict mode compliant.

So my question is: will a strict mode compliant version of the Google Maps application be available soon? Or will the current Google Maps application be replaced by a compliant one?

With kind regards,

Yoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should add this to the Maps API issue tracker

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

... note Google rarely comment on upcomming features. But by adding to the issue tracker. you 1) allow other developers to 'vote' on the suggestion - increasing its 'importance' to google developers and 2) allow you to get notifications if google do anything about it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. Earlier I had posted my question on the mailing list (google-maps-js-api-v3@googlegroups.com) but it was denied as it is a technical question and therefore more suited to be posted on StackOverflow instead. I have taken your advice and issued a feature request on the issue tracker. Hopefully I will get a reply from Google.

Comment: I could not find it in the issue tracker. Do you have a link?